# Generating Gaussian noise uncertainty?

Tags: matlab, noise

How can I generate non-stationary Gaussian noise (noise uncertainty) using Matlab? where the noise power fluctuate between $(1+p)^{-1}$ to $(1+p)$ where $p$ is the uncertainty factor in dB.

Best